# ASP .NET MVC Data type for image

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to upload an image and then convert it to base64.

What data type should I choose ? I tried string but it gives me only the file name but not it's path.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Test.Models.TestModel

<form asp-action="Test" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Image" class="form-control" type="file" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: you should use byte[]

Comment: @daremachine
If I just change it to public byte[] Image { get; set; } I get a "The value 'test.png' is not valid for Image." message on the form page.

Comment: read tutorials & learn more about asp core file upload. On the internet are plenty tutorials include microsoft pages.

Comment: You're only getting the filename, because your form doesn't have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use `IFormFile` type to upload an image and then convert it to base64 in controller. Here is my code:

**controller**

```
  public IActionResult FileUpLoad(Models.TestModel model)
        {
            //convert it to base64
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            model.Image.CopyTo(ms);
            var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

            //......
            
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**model**

```
public class TestModel

    {
       
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    }
```

**view**

```
<div>
    
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="FileUpLoad" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       
        <input type="file" asp-for="Image" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Upload an Image and then it can be converted to base64.**

[image]